# integer array to char pointer string

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to convert int array to char pointer string (array values converted to hex).I'm using codeblocks editor.
so,

```
                           int arr[4] = {30, 40, 15, 205};
```

should be converted to

```
                            char *str =  "1e280fcd";
```

I have written the following program to do so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *cur_str, *prev_str;
    char *comp_str, *comp_str_copy;
    int arr[] = {30,40,15,205}, i, j, arr_length;
    arr_length = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
    prev_str = malloc(sizeof(0));
    cur_str = malloc(sizeof(0));
    comp_str = malloc(sizeof(0));
    for(i=0;i<arr_length;i++)
    {
        cur_str = malloc(2);
        sprintf(cur_str,"%02x",arr[i]);

        comp_str = malloc(sizeof(cur_str)+sizeof(prev_str));
        sprintf(comp_str,"%s%s",prev_str,cur_str);
        printf("%s\n",comp_str);

        free(prev_str);
        prev_str = malloc(sizeof(comp_str));
        sprintf(prev_str,"%s",comp_str);

        if(i==(arr_length-1)){
            comp_str_copy = malloc(sizeof(comp_str));
            sprintf(comp_str_copy,"%s",comp_str);
        }

        free(comp_str);
        free(cur_str);
    }
    printf("%s %d\n",comp_str_copy,strlen(comp_str_copy));
    return 0;
}
```

This program's output is either

- segmentation fault or
- A string with garbage value in the initial locations

[image]

[image]

I've run the same program on different online compilers. They all give the correct string as output.Is the editor i'm using an issue or my memory management methods?

Comment: `sizeof(0)` is `sizeof(int)` which is mostly 4. `sizeof(cur_str)` and `sizeof(prev_str)` is `sizeof(char*)` which is probably 8. I think you meant `strlen` there.

Comment: Also don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. The *null-terminator* also needs space (which means a string of two characters need space for *three*).

Comment: Your output is pure text. Please copy&paste this text into your question instead of adding images. They don't add value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
    cur_str = malloc(2);
    sprintf(cur_str,"%02x",arr[i]);
```

the *sprintf* write 3 characters including the final null character, while you allocated only 2

In

```
comp_str = malloc(sizeof(cur_str)+sizeof(prev_str));
```

the allocate length is not the right one because the `size_of` do not return what you expect, must be

```
comp_str = malloc(strlen(cur_str)+strlen(prev_str)+1);
```

but of course that supposes `prev_str` is also a correct string at the beginning, and this is not the case

These two *malloc* will produce memory leaks because there are not free (nor used)

```
cur_str = malloc(sizeof(0));
comp_str = malloc(sizeof(0));
```

Why do you not use *realloc* to increase the size of `prev_str` ?

Note the final needed size is easy to know : `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) * 2 + 1` if numbers a limited to 255 (2 digits in hexa)

A proposal (without supposing all numbers < 256) :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {30,40,15,205};
    size_t arr_length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    size_t i;
    size_t sz = 0;
    char * r = malloc(0);

    for (i=0; i!= arr_length; ++i)
    {
      char s[20];
      int l = sprintf(s, "%02x",arr[i]);

      r = realloc(r, sz + l + 1);
      strcpy(r + sz, s);
      sz += l;
    }
    printf("%s %d\n", r, sz);
    free(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and xecution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wextra a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1e280fcd 8
```

Execution under *valgrind*

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ valgrind ./a.out
==2985== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2985== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2985== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2985== Command: ./a.out
==2985== 
1e280fcd 8
==2985== 
==2985== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2985==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2985==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 1,048 bytes allocated
==2985== 
==2985== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2985== 
==2985== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2985== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

That was a lot of dynamic memory allocation for a simple task. If the array and string will remain "small" then use the stack to your advantage:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int const arr[] = {30, 40, 15, 205};
    int const arr_length = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    char str[2 * arr_length + 1];
    int len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) {
        len += sprintf(&str[len], "%02x", arr[i]);
    }
    assert(len == 2 * arr_length);
    printf("%s %d\n", str, len);
    return 0;
}
```

But if you truly need a dynamic string, i.e.,`char *str` just modified `char str[2 * arr_length + 1];` to

```
char *str = malloc(2 * arr_length + 1);
```

and add `free(str);`

NB: All this assumes that you integer array values are less than 256.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. eliminates the unneeded code logic
2. eliminates the unneeded variables
3. eliminates the unneeded use of dynamic memory
4. cleanly compiles
5. does NOT seg fault
6. performs the desired functionality
7. note that `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`
8. note that `sizeof()` returns a `size_t` not a `int`
9. multiplies the length of the array `arr[]` by 2 to calculate the number of characters needed to display the converted array
10. adds 1 to the calculated length to allow for the trailing NUL byte
11. lists the variables in the necessary order so specific parameters are always available when needed

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    int arr[] = {30,40,15,205};
    char comp_str[ sizeof( arr )*2 +1 ] = {'\0'};  

    size_t arr_length = (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));

    for( size_t i=0; i<arr_length; i++ )
    {          
        sprintf( comp_str,"%s%02x", comp_str, arr[i] );
        printf("%s\n",comp_str);
    }
}
```

A run of the proposed code results in:

```
1e
1e28
1e280f
1e280fcd
```